# Execute function before refresh in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript

On `HTML` page, When user click / press `F5` button page refresh but before refresh I want to execute one function or a simple alert.

User can click on refresh button, press `F5` or `Ctrl + R.`

using `Angular`2/4

Comment: You can `implement OnInit` ngOnInit() { /** You want **/ } in `Component`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rely on browser events here.

```
window.onbeforeunload = (ev) => {
            this.myFunction();

            // OR

            this.yuorService.doActon().subscribe(() => {
                alert('did something before refresh');  
            });

             // OR

            alert('goin to refresh');

            // finally return the message to browser api.
            var dialogText = 'Changes that you made may not be saved.';
            ev.returnValue = dialogText;
            return dialogText;
    };
```

Comment: keep in mind that you want to inject that window somehow.

Comment: where to write/call this, in constructor() or in ngOnInit() ? @codeSetter

Comment: @codeSetter window is available by default, in _native javascript_, as you say. But with, say, universal rendering, using built-ins like `window` will break the build. Or if your app runs in webworker. Or some test environments. Or in any other edge case. Which is why it is recommended to inject it, with a simple wrapper if need be.

Comment: I don't understand - what's it got to do with happiness?

Comment: guys I write this in myComponent ngOnInit(), I got confirm dialog only when I hard refresh (ctrl+R) the page or while closing the tab, I want it on page refresh/reload/f5

Comment: post your code, because it need to wire up properly...  :)    its working fine in my app currently...

Answer (score 27):

The refresh of the page should trigger the event handler bound to `window:beforeunload`. **[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ve3mpy)** shows how to implement it for the "Home" component, using `HostListener`. You can test the page refresh by executing it **[in full page mode](https://angular-router-basic-example-ve3mpy.stackblitz.io/home)**.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class HomeViewComponent {

  @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
      console.log("Processing beforeunload...");
      // Do more processing...
      event.returnValue = false;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: +1. This is exactly what one using Angular2+ needs to catch browser tab refresh/close and do something before. If you do not want to get the confirm leave confirmation dialog, just do nothing (do not assign returnValue).

Comment: Is there any way to capture the reload and cancel button event ?. Because when click the reload button. I need to perform some action. If it's canceled I don't need to perform anything

Comment: How do you unsubscribe from that inside ngOnDestroy?

Comment: @ConnorsFan BUt, I want `shift + f5` or `ctrl + f5`.  Only force clear cache reload before the call events.

Comment: Do not use `event.returnValue` if you do not want the confirm dialog.